# Why can't i disable the "Next" button on my custom page on Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

This is not working as I want it to. My code is stripped down.

- `InitializeWizard`:

```
    procedure InitializeWizard();
    var
      strBackupFolder: String;

    begin
      idAutoBackupPage := pageAutoBackup_CreatePage(wpSelectTasks)

      { Backup Local Path }
      strBackupFolder := '';
      if (IsWin64) then
      begin
        RegQueryStringValue(HKLM64,
                'Software\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Options',
                'BackupAtShutdownLocalPath', strBackupFolder);
      end else
      begin
        RegQueryStringValue(HKLM,
                'Software\MeetSchedAssist\Meeting Schedule Assistant\Options',
                'BackupAtShutdownLocalPath', strBackupFolder);
      end;

      textBackupFolder.Text  := strBackupFolder;

    end;
```

So our control has the path from the reg. I have set my path in the reg to empty (like a new install).

- `CurPageChanged`

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = pageAutoBackup.ID then
  begin
    EnableAutoBackupSettingsNextPageButton();
  end;
end;
```

This is the code for the EnableAuto... routine:

```
procedure EnableAutoBackupSettingsNextPageButton();
begin
    if(radBackupWhatNone.Checked = False) then
    begin
        { Can we proceed? }
        if(DirExists(textBackupFolder.Text)) then
        begin
          { Yes, it is OK to proceed }
          Wizardform.NextButton.Enabled := True
        end
        else begin
          { No, it is NOT to proceed }
          Wizardform.NextButton.Enabled := True;
        end;
    end else
        { OK to proceed with Next }
        Wizardform.NextButton.Enabled := True;
end;

{ Sets the state of the controls }
procedure EnableAutoBackupSettingPageControls(bEnable: Boolean);
begin
    pnlBackupMode.Enabled := bEnable;
    lblBackupMode.Enabled := bEnable;
    radBackupModeAuto.Enabled := bEnable;
    radBackupModeManual.Enabled := bEnable;
    lblPromptMode.Enabled := bEnable;
    cmbPromptMode.Enabled := bEnable;
    lblBackupFolder.Enabled := bEnable;
    textBackupFolder.Enabled := bEnable;
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Enabled := bEnable;

    EnableAutoBackupSettingsNextPageButton();
end;
```

In short, it needs to enable the radio controls as needed and enable the **Next** wizard button.

Finally:

- I have some action handlers:

```
{ Ask user to select the backup Folder location }
procedure btnSelectBackupFolder_Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  strFolder: string;
begin
    strFolder := textBackupFolder.Text;

    { Display Browse Window }
    if(BrowseForFolder('', strFolder, True)) then
    begin
      textBackupFolder.Text := strFolder;
    end;
end;

{ Action handler }
procedure radBackupWhatNone_Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    { Set control states }
    EnableAutoBackupSettingPageControls(False);

end;

{ Action handler }
procedure radBackupWhatComplete_Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    { Set control states }
    EnableAutoBackupSettingPageControls(True);

end;

{ Action handler }
procedure radBackupWhatEssential_Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    { Set control states }
    EnableAutoBackupSettingPageControls(True);

end;

{ Ask user to select the backup Folder location }
procedure btnSelectBackupFolder_Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  strFolder: string;
begin
    strFolder := textBackupFolder.Text;

    { Display Browse Window }
    if(BrowseForFolder('', strFolder, True)) then
    begin
      textBackupFolder.Text := strFolder;
    end;

    EnableAutoBackupSettingsNextPageButton();
end;
```

When I run this code, and the page is activated, all controls are emabled correctly expect for the main wizard Next button. It is still true. And when I click the radio options. the primary controls enable / disable. But not the Next button.

Answer (score 0):

This [article](https://www.generacodice.com/en/articolo/339668/How-to-disable-the-%238220%3BNext%238221%3B-button-on-the-wizard-form-in-Inno-Setup) helped me. It was referring to the **Cancel** button and said:

> Also another way of manually doing this is:
>
> ```
> procedure DisableCancelButton();
> begin
>   WizardForm.CancelButton.Enabled := False;
>   WizardForm.Update;
> end;
>
> procedure EnableCancelButton();
> begin
>   WizardForm.CancelButton.Enabled := True;
>   WizardForm.Update;
> end;
> ```

But the principle was the same. So I adjusted this method:

```
{ Sets the state of the controls }
procedure EnableAutoBackupSettingPageControls(bEnable: Boolean);
begin
    pnlBackupMode.Enabled := bEnable;
    lblBackupMode.Enabled := bEnable;
    radBackupModeAuto.Enabled := bEnable;
    radBackupModeManual.Enabled := bEnable;
    lblPromptMode.Enabled := bEnable;
    cmbPromptMode.Enabled := bEnable;
    lblBackupFolder.Enabled := bEnable;
    textBackupFolder.Enabled := bEnable;
    btnSelectBackupFolder.Enabled := bEnable;

    if(radBackupWhatNone.Checked = True) then
      Wizardform.NextButton.Enabled := True
    else
      Wizardform.NextButton.Enabled := DirExists(textBackupFolder.Text);
    WizardForm.Update;
end;
```

And I adjusted this one:

```
{ Ask user to select the backup Folder location }
procedure btnSelectBackupFolder_Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  strFolder: string;
begin
    strFolder := textBackupFolder.Text;

    { Display Browse Window }
    if(BrowseForFolder('', strFolder, True)) then
    begin
      textBackupFolder.Text := strFolder;

      Wizardform.NextButton.Enabled := DirExists(textBackupFolder.Text);
      WizardForm.Update;
    end;
end;
```

---

I also had to add the `CurPageChanged` handler:

```
procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = pageAutoBackup.ID then
  begin
    { Get the state of the Next button correct }
    if(radBackupWhatNone.Checked = True) then
      Wizardform.NextButton.Enabled := True
    else
      Wizardform.NextButton.Enabled := DirExists(textBackupFolder.Text);
    WizardForm.Update;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I believe you still need to update the "Next" button state in the `CurPageChanged`. When the users goes back from your custom page, the "Next" button gets enabled. When the user revisits your custom page, the "Next" button would stay enabled, no matter that your custom page controls state is.

Comment: Imo, turning `bEnable` from argument to a variable and doing `bEnable := radBackupWhatComplete.Checked or radBackupWhatEssential.Checked` and calling `EnableAutoBackupSettingPageControls` (without parameter) from all `xxx_Click` handlers and `CurPageChanged` would be a more clean solution. And then you will actually need only one `Click` handler, not three.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl At the moment I am moving my code out into a distinct ISS file and added handlers for the `InitializeWizard` etc that get called from the main script. It is working. I think I follow you but am not 100% sure. Where would the setting of this `bEnable` be made? In `InitializeWizard`?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl The second panel of controls enable based on the user clicking the radio buttons. This is why I had to add 3 click handlers. I don't quite understand how I can get away from have those three handlers.

Comment: `bEnable := radBackupWhatComplete.Checked or radBackupWhatEssential.Checked` should be the first line in `EnableAutoBackupSettingPageControls`.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Understood. I made that change and agree it is simpler. And I now understand what you mean about the click handler. Good logic. Thanks. :)